# Python - Attribute dynamic name DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, dataframe

I would like open several files (csv) with a loop. 
The problem is that I can not give dynamic names and so I open a single dataframe instead of 12.

All my paths are in a dictionary.

```
Key         Value
key1        D:/Users/Documents/file1-key1.csv
            D:/Users/Documents/file2-key1.csv
key2        D:/Users/Documents/file3-key2.csv
            D:/Users/Documents/file2-key2.csv
```

Here is my code :

```
l=0
for key, value in dicstagefolder.items():
    for value in value:
        l=l+1
        name = key+"-"+str(l)
        name= pd.read_csv(value)
```

Thanks, Laurent

Comment: Use a list or a dict to store the DataFrames, or handle them in memory one at a time.

Comment: Thanks miradulo I store my dataframes in a list. But how I can attribute a name to my differents dataframes ?

Comment: Set an attribute on each DataFrame? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I have 12 files csv in my repository. I want load them all at once and give a name for each file (dataframe load) load. I hope to be clearer.

Comment: By _name_, do you mean you want a different variable in memory for each of these DataFrames?

Comment: Yes it's the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign your DataFrames to values in a dictionary and change the key for each DataFrame. Ex

```
    dict_of_dfs = {}
    l=0
    for key, value in dicstagefolder.items():
        for v in value:
            l=l+1
            name = key+"-"+str(l)
            dict_of_dfs.update(**{name: pd.read_csv(v)})
```

Also, try using for v in value in your inner loop. Otherwise, you might face problems with the value keyword getting overwritten.